# IE8 - Iframe css sandboxed

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a `<style>...</style>` tag on some `iframe` in my page... these Iframes are from the same origin, so, I can access them from the main page.

In most of browsers that stylesheet tag is being applied only in the corrisponding iframe, but, when the browser is `IE8` the stylesheet is applied even to the main page.

I tried the attribute `sandbox`, but, it doesn't solve my problem... because I need to access to `iframe.contentWindow.document` property...

How can I make that stylesheet scoped to the corresponding iframe only??

---

**EDITS**

```js
// application.js
function EditIframeCtrl() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('test');

  var style = "<style type='text/css'>body { background: red; }</style>";
  var page = "<html><head>"+ style +"</head><body></body></html>";

  iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/html');
  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(page);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', EditIframeCtrl);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="iframetest.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- iframetest.html -->
<h1>this is just for having a same origin iframe</h1>
```

Comment: Um, a stylesheet inside an iframe should NOT change the parent. Show your code so we can see what is up.

Comment: Can you provide a working sample?

Comment: Do you have the meta tag placed in your code as `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>` ?

Comment: @epascarello, I guess his stylesheet is outside his iframe. Hitmands, am I correct?

Comment: I made an edit.
@DavidR no, I didn't placed that `meta`.
@epascarello his stylesheet is inside of his iframe...

Comment: @DavidR I placed that `meta` but without any result.